# Determine Noise Level by Convolving N Signals

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, convolution

I using a microphone to determine (air) leakage characteristics. The signals need to be filtered to reduce the noise level and i thought of using the **Spectral Subtraction Technique**. Since im having 4 leakage-free sampled signals im thinking to correlate all of them to 1 signal that captures most of the overall noise level.

Is this a good approach to determine the noise? How can i convolve 4 Signals into 1?

Edit: As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#:%7E:text=a%20moving%20average%20is%20a%20type%20of%20convolution%20and%20so%20it%20can%20be%20viewed%20as%20an%20example%20of%20a%20low%2Dpass%20filter%20used%20in%20signal%20processing) is not an reliable source i am not certain if the convolution is a a type of moving average which can be viewed as low-pass filter used in signal processing. Therefore im not sure what **averaging type or convolution** should be used in this case.

[image: 4 leakage-free signals]

The outlier at the beginning of the sequence is due to pressing a button on the PCB.

Edit: I tried to do simple signal averaging of all 4 signals and ploted the result (see below zoomed in version). Is this the right way to do this?

[image: zoomed in noise level averaging]